# Scope of the 'read-only' flag when mounting a volume in Docker

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I am attempting to achieve a setup with directories

```
/foo
/foo/bar
```

Where `/foo/bar` is a directory mounted from the local file system but `/foo` is not. I would like `/foo/bar` to be read-only, but `/foo` to be read-write. Is this achievable in Docker?

Answer (score 2):

Well, heck, let's try it.

```
$ mkdir /tmp/data
$ docker run -it --rm -v /tmp/data:/foo/bar:ro busybox sh
/ # cd /foo
/foo # echo look I can write files here > testfile
/foo # cd bar
/foo/bar # echo but here not so much > testfile
sh: can't create testfile: Read-only file system
```

So it looks like the answer is, "yes."